# textbox style when selected Html/ModX

Tags: html, css, modx

I want to create an style for my search-box. Its the search-box from [THIS](http://www.baansportopende.nl/) site. I know that :active sort of does the trick but the effect just lasts for a split second. I am currently using modX so my code is currently swarming with modX terms but ill post it anyway.

---

```
<form class="sisea-search-form" action="[[~[[+landing:default=`[[*id]]`]]]]" method="[[+method:default=`get`]]">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="search"> Zoeken naar:</label>
    <input type="text" name="[[+searchIndex]]" id="[[+searchIndex]]" value="[[+searchValue]]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="[[+landing:default=[[*id]]]]" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="[[%sisea.search? &namespace=`sisea` &topic=`default`]]" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

```
.sisea-search-form{
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #555555;
  margin-top:10px;
}
.sisea-search-form label{
  margin-left: 15px;
  cursor: default;
}
#search:active{
  border-width:5px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:black;
}
.sisea-search-form input[type="text"]{
  width:130px;
}
.sisea-search-form input[type="submit"]{
  width:55px;
}
```

---

```
<h3>Search</h3>
        [[!SimpleSearchForm? &tpl=`simpleSearchTpl` &landing=`58` ]]
[[-<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="#">
    <div class="zoekVeld">

        <input type="submit" class="searchButton" value="Zoeken">
    </div>
</form>]]
```

---

The last part is modX but should not be necessary for my question. 
Cheers, Marco.

---

EDIT

---

I want a combination of both the active and focus selector. so i guess you could say an extended active . or you could say a focus selector which decays after a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I did a little trick for ya.

On :active, keep your css, but add a :focus class with those styles :

```
input:focus{
    border-width:5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:transparent;
    -webkit-transition : border-color 0.5s
    -moz-transition : border-color 0.5s
    -o-transition : border-color 0.5s
    transition : border-color 0.5s
}
```

I did a fiddle, you just have to adsjust value to get what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/kDqhP/

Comment: this is also sort-of what i want. I want a combination of both the active and focus selector. so i guess you could say an extended active . or you could say a focus selector which decays after a few seconds.

Comment: Edited my answer, that will do what you want (i hope)

Comment: It will do ;) thank you for your time. I really appreciate it.